# SSMS Hangs then crashes when I have an add in installed

Tags: ssms, ssms-addin

I open up SSMS 17 and it hangs before the login screen appears. Then it crashes. I tried with SSMS 2016 and below, all had the same problem.

I have an add-in installed; when I remove it the problem goes away. The problem here is that I need the add-in to be running.
I tried repairing SSMS. It didn't work. Re-installing the add-in also didn't work.

The other day all worked fine, I didn't have any problems nor did I update SSMS or the add-in.

The Event Viewer error:

> ```
> The program Ssms.exe version 2017.140.17224.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
>  Process ID: 30a8
>  Start Time: 01d3bf84d779c54f
>  Termination Time: 34
>  Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
>  Report Id: 4ed51b90-2b78-11e8-837f-ac9e17830287
>  Faulting package full name: 
>  Faulting package-relative application ID:
> ```

Comment: There's not enough information there for us to help really. You could try debugging the process, breaking and seeing what the stuck threads are doing, but chances are you'd do better going directly to the authors of the add-in.

Comment: Tried using a different add in and there was no problem. I'll def contact the add in authors about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling add-in, cleaning its folders in Program Files, Program Data (if any), AppData/Local or Roaming (again if any). You can also check temp folder "%temp%" and clear it. Restart the machine, reinstall add-in. The issue should go away unless the add-in is faulty/broken.